# What happened to my rat?

Tags: health, eating, rat

Last night I noticed my rat ate little to no food, which is odd because she usually eats a fair amount. I took her out of her cage to look at her and her left eye was closed and had red goobers along with her red stained nose. This morning when I woke up I looked at her again and her whole jaw was covered in mucus and she is still producing more, I don’t think she is choking and I can’t think of anything else it might be. We gave her pain medications and antibiotics.

Comment: You need to take your pet to the vet right away. We can not help you over the internet.

Comment: I don't know what it is but the same thing happens with one of my hamsters as well. One of his eyes were wide shut. Two days later he passed away. You really need to take her to a vet ASAP.